# Bat file to only generate a MD5 checksum for a file

Tags: windows, batch-file, md5

I've been looking for a method to create a bat file to generate the MD5 checksum of a file.

I tried `fciv` and a few others, but they all generate a file with additional info such as path and file name etc. I just need the MD5, nothing else.

Anyone point me in the right direction?

This command line

```
fciv new.xml -md5 -r -xml new.xml.md5
```

creates a file with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FCIV>
    <FILE_ENTRY><name>new.xml</name><MD5>OuX4jSQyl91+M1fUQZeGtw==</MD5></FILE_ENTRY></FCIV>
```

I just need the MD5 checksum.

Comment: Provide us with the command you used with fciv and the output it provided then show use from the output what it was specifically that you needed.

Comment: check this - https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/md5.bat

Comment: @npocmaka nice batch, had to disable the dirtest, always reclaimed file being a dir. I replaced it with `for %%# in ("%~1") Do Echo %%~a#|find "d">NUL 2>&1 &&(echo %~1 is a directory&exit /b 3)`

Comment: @LotPings Or to avoid the extra thread spawned by `find` there you could just say `if exist "%~1\NUL"`

Comment: There is the command line tool `CertUtil.exe` that supports computing hash values like MD5 and SHA1 -- type `CertUtil -hashfile -?`...

Comment: @aschipfl npocmaka's batch wraps certutil to get rid of additional lines and remove the spaces from the md5.

Comment: dbenham also wrote a wrapper for certutil. http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7592

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the FCIV tool you have shown in your question, you seem to be outputting your result in base64 in an XML, when that isn't what you've asked.

You may be able to still use it like this to get the MD5 of a file called new.xml:

```dos
For /F "EOL=/" %A In ('FCIV new.xml') Do @Echo(%A
```

This assumes MD5 is still the default output of FCIV and it is ran from a cmd.exe window which correctly knows/accesses the location of FCIV.exe

**[Edit /]**

An extended example in batch file format.

```dos
@Echo Off
Set "MyFile=new.xml"
Set "MD5="
For /F "EOL=/" %%A In ('FCIV "%MyFile%"') Do Set "MD5=%%A"
If Defined MD5 Echo(%MD5%
Timeout -1
```

The word new.xml could even be replaced with %~1 and you could then just drag and drop a file onto it to output it's hash.

Comment: thanks, appreciate your reply.. that works exactly as you have described, I however need it to work in a bat file as I am generating the new.xml using the bat file first, once new.xml is generated I need the bat file to generate a md5 file (new.xml.md5) of new.xml.

Comment: Thank you, lines 4 and 5 tweaked was all I needed for my existing file. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very reduced wrapper for certutil without any arg/error checking:

```
@Echo off
:: Pass the file to hash as the only arg
Set "MD5="
For /f "skip=1 Delims=" %%# in (
  'certutil -hashfile "%~f1" MD5'
) Do If not defined MD5 Set MD5=%%#
Set MD5=%MD5: =%
Echo:%MD5%
```

Output hashing this batch itself

```
b873bbcd93873a6aa320cd64a1751d8a
```